# If l had a car, l would give you a lift. (Begin the sentence with 'Had')

Tags: sentence-construction

If l had a car, l would give you a lift. (Begin the sentence with 'Had').
I find an answer which confused me that is 'Had l a car, l would give you a lift.' Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of inverting a subject and auxiliary verb to create an unreal conditional, similar using *[ "if" + simple past/past perfect ]*.

> **Had I** seen you, I would have stopped to say hello.
> **Were I** available, I would happily accept your invitation.

It doesn't work with auxiliary "do" or with modal verbs:

> <del>**Did I** exercise more, I would be in better shape.</del>
> <del>**Could I** sing better, I would be in a band.</del>

In some varieties of English, particularly British ones, this structure works with *possessive "have"*, which is what you have in your example. Here's another:

> **Had I** a pen, I would lend it to you.